# Learning new racial motifs

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I've already figured out that there are books that are called something like: "Racial Motifs 9 the Argonians" and I assume that those teach you a new Armor/Weapon style. However what I don't get is where I can find such a book. Is it a rare drop or can it be bought? Also if this doesn't teach you how to craft stuff with a new style how can I learn on my Argonian the Nordic style for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Racial Motif books teach you how to craft weapons and armour in that races style.

They do indeed get bought/traded in Zone chat, and sold in Guild Stores, often for around 1k gold.

However from my experience, video guides, and forums, the books seem to be most likely to spawn in Nightstands, Dressers, Trunks, Cabinets and Cupboards.

Due to this many sources suggest farming through NPC houses and Inns, as these containers are often "near beds".

For example:

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to assume that the Racial Motifs books teach your character how to craft items in another's race's style.

The best way to find these books is to search bookcases in  the world. Dungeons and instances are more likely to hold these books than towns. Once you reach level 14+ areas, you should see them *much* more often (this was the case when I played Daggerfall, however I distinctly remember 'The Mysterious Curio' sent you to an abandoned library with at least one of those books). Otherwise, try to check out your guild's store (if you're in a guild), someone might be selling it.

Comment: Also, if you watch zone chat, people are often selling them for around 1k gold. If you find duplicates, people are usually willing to trade as well.